# How to I manipulate form.as_p in a Django form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, forms

I am trying to submit two forms at once. And It appears that I have to use {{form.as_p}}. But now I face two problems. 1. How do I get the id of {{form.as_p}}. 2. Within each form I have input fields. How do I edit the width of these fields? Thank you!

```
<form  id = "form" action="." method="POST">{% csrf_token %}    
  
    {{form1.as_p}}  

<div >
    <input id = "geoButton" type="button" class = "btn" value="{{geoFormButtonValue}}" onclick = "formHandler()" />
</div>

<hr>
    
    {{form2.as_p}}

        
<div >
    <input id = "totalRiskButton" type="button" class = "btn" value="{{geoFormButtonValue}}" onclick = "formHandler2()" />
</div>

</form>

    <div>
    <input type="button" class = "btn" value="Run" onclick="SubmitForm()" style="float:right"/>
    </div>
```

Original Code: I originally had two forms separately. However, when I submited the form I was not able to get the data through the ".cleaned_data" method. To be more specific, I was only able to get the data from form2.

## html

```
<form  id = "form1" action="." method="POST">{% csrf_token %}   
  
<div class=".col1" style="float:left;margin-left:1%">           

    {{ form.region }}

    {{ form.operator }}
</div>

<div id = "form1_value" class="col-xs-2" >
    {{ form.value }}
</div>
    
</form>

<div >
    <input id = "geoButton" type="button" class = "btn" value="{{geoFormButtonValue}}" onclick = "formHandler()" />
</div>


<hr>

<h1 style="font-size:15px;color:#337AC7;font-weight:bold">Total Risk Constraint</h1>            

  
<form  id = "form2" action="." method="POST">{% csrf_token %}   
<div class=".col1" style="float:left;margin-left:1%">           
            
    {{ form2.operator }}
    
</div>
        
<div id = "form2_value" class="col-xs-2" >
    {{ form2.totalRiskValue }}
</div>
</form> 
        
<div >
    <input id = "totalRiskButton" type="button" class = "btn" value="{{geoFormButtonValue}}" onclick = "formHandler2()" />
</div>

<hr >



<div>
<input type="button" class = "btn" value="Run" onclick="SubmitForm1()" style="float:right"/>
</div>
```

## views.py

```
 if request.method == 'POST':
   
    constraintform = constraintListForm1(request.POST)         
    if constraintform.is_valid():         
        data = constraintform.cleaned_data
        print(data)    
        region = data['region']
        operator = data['operator']
        value = data['value']                        
        constraint = [region, operator, value]
        
    constraintform2 = constraintListForm2(request.POST)
    if constraintform2.is_valid():
        data = constraintform2.cleaned_data
        operator = data['operator']
        totalRiskValue = data['totalRiskValue']
        totalRiskConstraint = [operator, totalRiskValue]
```

Comment: You don't *have* to use `form.as_p`. But what do you mean by the "id"? And you change the length of those fields via the form definitions.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Hi Daniel. Thanks for the quick reply. Can I submit two forms (i.e. <form id = "form1> and <form id = "form2">, with one button? I tried that but I was not able to get all the data from the form. So I researched online, and it appears the suggested way is to use form.as_p.

Comment: @To answer your question, I have a button following each of the form. The button is to control the visibility of the form. Therefore I need to link the button to the id of each of the form.

Comment: These two things have nothing whatsoever to do with each other. `form.as_p` is one way of outputting all the fields in a form at one go. It really has nothing at all to do with "submitting two forms" at the same time. Note that in the code here, you have both forms within the same HTML `<form>` element, so your button *will* submit them both at once. And if you want to show/hide things on a button click, put them inside `<div>` elements with your choice of ID.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I added my original code. It works fine until I tried to submit both of the forms at the same time.  As I was not able to get the data from form 1.

Comment: That's not real code. For one thing, you need to call `is_valid()` before you can access `cleaned_data`. Please show your actual view.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Just edited. The problem is that I can't get the data from from1. The problem started when I added form 2. Before, when i submitted only form 1, it was fine.